# How to delete a shared memory file created by another user?

Tags: linux, memory, shared

I am just running into a problem with the permissions of /dev/shm:
I have an suite of software, which multiple users should be able to use.
Permissions of shared resources are given by using the same group.
But in case of shared memory I am running into this problem:

- a c-program run by user "a" should be able to remove a shared memory in /dev/shm, which was created by user "b"
- due to the sticky bit of /dev/shm it is forbidden to delete a shared memory of another user - even if both users and the shared memory are belonging to the same group
- creating a subdirectory in /dev/shm with appropriate permissions does not work since inner '/' are not allowed in the filename used by shm_open()

Well, I do not want to remove the sticky bit of /dev/shm since this is linux standard.

E.g. it would be very fine if there was a possibility to place the shared memory files of my application suite in another directory than /dev/shm - ideally a subdirectory of /dev/shm. But I did not find any hint how to do this.

Does anyone has an idea, how to allow user "a" to delete a shared memory created by user "b"?

Comment: you cannot place it somewhere else. `/dev/shm` is only a virtual filesystem to represent shared memory objects.

Answer (score 1):

> it would be very fine if there was a possibility to place the shared memory files of my application suite in another directory than /dev/shm

There's nothing special about files used by `shm_open()` other than they have to be in `/dev/shm`.  You can `mmap()` any file with shared access exactly the same way.

Don't use `shm_open()` to open a file for use as shared memory. The only thing `shm_open()` really does is give you a file descriptor to a file located in `/dev/shm`. [This is the entirety of glibc's `shm_open()` implementation](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=sysdeps/posix/shm_open.c;hb=HEAD):

```
/* Open shared memory object.  */
int
shm_open (const char *name, int oflag, mode_t mode)
{
  SHM_GET_NAME (EINVAL, -1, "");

  oflag |= O_NOFOLLOW | O_CLOEXEC;

  /* Disable asynchronous cancellation.  */
  int state;
  pthread_setcancelstate (PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE, &state);

  int fd = open (shm_name, oflag, mode);
  if (fd == -1 && __glibc_unlikely (errno == EISDIR))
    /* It might be better to fold this error with EINVAL since
       directory names are just another example for unsuitable shared
       object names and the standard does not mention EISDIR.  */
    __set_errno (EINVAL);

  pthread_setcancelstate (state, NULL);

  return fd;
}
```

All that does is make sure the file name is for a file in `/dev/shm`.

Just replace `shm_open()` with a plain `open()` and put your shared memory file where you want.

Instead of

```
int fd = shm_open( "shared_memory_file", oflag, mode );
```

simply use

```
int fd = open( "/path/to/my/shared_memory_file", oflag, mode );
```

Comment: Dont do that. That way you end up with a regular file. The point in beeing in `/dev/shm` is that its not a real file but a part in memory. If you do what this answer suggests, you may have very slow access times (e.g. 10 clients access on a hdd or smth) as its a regular file on your filesystem (that even stays there after boot)

Comment: @Nidhoegger Have you actually benchmarked that?  And you can just pick a directory in a [`tmpfs` filesystem](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/tmpfs.5.html) if you want a memory-based file system.  Again, there's **nothing** special about `shm_open()`.  It merely opens a **regular file** in `/dev/shm`.  Oh, and makes sure the "close-on-exec" flag is set on the file descriptor.

Comment: Actually I have. It does not matter for 2kb shared memory files as these are cached, but it makes a substential difference when using more than 5MB files (I use SHM for IPC and just for shits and giggles I changed the path right now and its substentially slower). There is nothing special about `shm_open`, there **is** something special about `/dev/shm`, even in comparison to `tmpfs` (which again is a real filesystem with all filesystem overhead that `/dev/shm` does not have).

Comment: Very interesting background information - thank you very much. In fact, what I need is shared memory for interprocess communication. The representation of shared memory as a file is a very nice feature of linux for debugging. My problem is, that a user starts a program which creates the shared memory to communicate with a daemon (which is running with user privileges). Unfortunately first the user program ends and now it is left to the daemon to remove the shared memory. The sticky bit of /dev/shm prevents the daemon to remove the shared memory.

Comment: @Nidhoegger *there is something special about `/dev/shm`, even in comparison to `tmpfs`*  Ummm, every Linux system I just looked on, `/dev/shm` **IS** a `tmpfs` filesystem.  See https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt:  "glibc 2.2 and above expects tmpfs to be mounted at /dev/shm for
   POSIX shared memory"

Comment: @colouredbird You can use **any** file as shared memory. Just `mmap()` it with the `MAP_SHARED` flag in all the process(es) that need shared memory - just like you do with the `fd` from `shm_open()`. The only thing special about using `shm_open()` is it forces the file to be in `/dev/shm`.  You can put **your** file anywhere you like - just be aware that the location can have other impacts - just as with any data file you might want to use.  You can control it any way you want.  If you put it somewhere only the daemon user has write access to, then no one (barring `root`...) can cause problems

Comment: If you need to start using shared files as IPC you should overthink your IPC mechanism and maybe switch to something else (e.g. Named Pipes, POSIX Message Queues or plain Unix Sockets)

Comment: Thank you very much. I replaced shm_open() and shm_unlink() with open() and unlink(), changed from /dev/shm to /tmp/mydirectory and added the flags O_NOFOLLOW and O_CLOEXEC. My functionality problem is solved and using shared memory segments of 64K and 1M, I do not observe any impact to the performance.

Comment: @nidhoegger: Yes, I would have liked to use POSIX Message Queues. In fact, this was the original idea for the IPC I wanted. 4 years ago we came to the design decision to use shared memory instead of mqueue, so I do not remember clearly. If I remember correctly is the requirement to allocate at system start the memory all queues ever would need the reason to do something different.